# I want keycloak to protect my webapplication api ,such as /user/create

Tags: keycloak

I configured the client, corresponding roles, corresponding policies, corresponding permissions, and corresponding resources on the keycloak. Then, I tied the role to a user, but when I logged in with that user, without protecting my page, I could go directly to the interface of the application I developed, such as/test.
I show you my code below:

this is my springboot application.yml，
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBwJr.png)

This is the api I want to protect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1umOE.png)

sorry,My picture doesn't seem to fit,

I want to protect my api ,you know like RBAC ,permission ,resource, role,user

Comment: Please add configuration, code etc. as text. Images are a pain to read and makes it hard to copy and paste code.

Comment: wait a minute ,I just released my Java code.

Comment: Thank you. Please edit your question rather than adding it as an answer.